# Mysql and java error based on dates and displaying

Tags: java, mysql

**Below is a code for my java application where it is using mysql to pull a students table in the database filled with students data. The below code specifically allows you to manage that data in terms of removing or deleting a particular student.**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
//import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class manage_students_form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    students stdnt = new students();
    public manage_students_form() {
        initComponents();

        stdnt.fillStudentJtable(jTable1, "");
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        manage_student_form = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        title_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        first_name_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        last_name_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        gender_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dob_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        phone_number_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        email_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        physical_address_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        residence_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        student_id_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        last_name_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        phone_number_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        email_address_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        residence_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        male_radiobutton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        female_radiobutton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        physical_address_TextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        edit_student_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cancel_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        dateChooser = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();
        first_name_textfield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        student_id_label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        remove_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        manage_student_form.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 153));

        title_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 28)); // NOI18N
        title_label.setText("Manage Students");

        first_name_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        first_name_label.setText("FirstName");

        last_name_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        last_name_label.setText("LastName");

        gender_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        gender_label.setText("Gender");

        dob_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        dob_label.setText("Date of Birth");

        phone_number_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        phone_number_label.setText("Phone Number");

        email_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        email_label.setText("Email Address");

        physical_address_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        physical_address_label.setText("Physical Address");

        residence_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        residence_label.setText("Residence");

        phone_number_textfield.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                phone_number_textfieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        phone_number_textfield.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                phone_number_textfieldKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        male_radiobutton.setText("Male");

        female_radiobutton.setText("Female");

        physical_address_TextArea.setColumns(20);
        physical_address_TextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(physical_address_TextArea);

        edit_student_button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        edit_student_button.setText("Edit Student");
        edit_student_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                edit_student_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cancel_button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        cancel_button.setText("Cancel");
        cancel_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cancel_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        student_id_label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        student_id_label.setText("Student ID");

        remove_button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
        remove_button.setText("Remove");
        remove_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                remove_buttonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Student ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Gender", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Email Address", "Physical Address", "Residence"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout manage_student_formLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(manage_student_form);
        manage_student_form.setLayout(manage_student_formLayout);
        manage_student_formLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(157, 157, 157)
                .addComponent(title_label))
            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(phone_number_label)
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addComponent(phone_number_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(dob_label)
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addComponent(dateChooser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(email_label)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(email_address_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(student_id_label)
                                .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                                .addComponent(student_id_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(first_name_label)
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addComponent(first_name_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(last_name_label)
                                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                                .addComponent(last_name_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(gender_label)
                                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                .addComponent(male_radiobutton)
                                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                                .addComponent(female_radiobutton)))))
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1010, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(physical_address_label)
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(remove_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(103, 103, 103)
                .addComponent(edit_student_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                .addComponent(cancel_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(residence_label)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(residence_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 203, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        manage_student_formLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(title_label)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(student_id_label)
                            .addComponent(student_id_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(first_name_label)
                            .addComponent(first_name_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(last_name_label)
                            .addComponent(last_name_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(gender_label)
                            .addComponent(male_radiobutton)
                            .addComponent(female_radiobutton))
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(phone_number_label)
                            .addComponent(phone_number_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(dob_label)
                            .addComponent(dateChooser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(email_label)
                            .addComponent(email_address_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 403, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(physical_address_label))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(remove_button))
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(edit_student_button))
                    .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(cancel_button)))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(manage_student_formLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(residence_label)
                    .addComponent(residence_textfield, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(manage_student_form, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(manage_student_form, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void phone_number_textfieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                      

    private void phone_number_textfieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                
        if(!Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar())){
            evt.consume();
        }
    }                                               

    private void edit_student_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

//         

    }                                                   

    private void cancel_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        System.exit(0);
    }                                             

    private void remove_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
     int rowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();


        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        if(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 3).toString().equals("Male") ){
        male_radiobutton.setSelected(true);
        female_radiobutton.setSelected(false);

        }else{
            female_radiobutton.setSelected(true);
            male_radiobutton.setSelected(false);
        }

         student_id_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0).toString());
         first_name_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1).toString());
         last_name_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 2).toString());
         phone_number_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 5).toString());
          email_address_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 6).toString());
           physical_address_TextArea.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 7).toString());
         residence_textfield.setText(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 8).toString());
```

**Whatever row of data you select it should fetch from the students table and fill the fields in the "manage students form" java form automatically depending on the selected data. The problem is it fetches and displays data for all fields in the table, but does not  fetch 'date of birth' data from my database and display it and it doesn't change the 'date of birth' of a selected student based on that particular student.**

```
//         Date dob;
//        try {
//            dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 4).toString());
//           dateChooser.getSelectedDate(dob);
//        } catch (ParseException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(manage_students_form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        }

    }                                    


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new manage_students_form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton cancel_button;
    private datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo dateChooser;
    private javax.swing.JLabel dob_label;
    private javax.swing.JButton edit_student_button;
    private javax.swing.JTextField email_address_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JLabel email_label;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton female_radiobutton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel first_name_label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField first_name_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JLabel gender_label;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel last_name_label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField last_name_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton male_radiobutton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel manage_student_form;
    private javax.swing.JLabel phone_number_label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField phone_number_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea physical_address_TextArea;
    private javax.swing.JLabel physical_address_label;
    private javax.swing.JButton remove_button;
    private javax.swing.JLabel residence_label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField residence_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JLabel student_id_label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField student_id_textfield;
    private javax.swing.JLabel title_label;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I have tried:

`Date dob;
        try {
           dob = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 4).toString());
           dateChooser.getSelectedDate(dob);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(manage_students_form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }`

but its not working.
How can I correct this. The issue is the date function. Kindly help.**

***[This is the manage students form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbcUE.png)***

Comment: Can you let me know the value you are getting for the below line of code 
          model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 4).toString()

Comment: @RamachandraReddy The value I am getting is the default date of the date chooser yet its supposed to change from whatever date to a specific date of the student you have clicked. Just like in model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1).toString() it displays the first name of the student in the database.

Comment: I guess the toString() method is causing the issue. Because what you are getting from rowindex would be a date and you are converting it to String. I can provide you a solution if you can get me the value that you are passing to parse method of SimpleDateFormat. The value can be default and current date.

Comment: @RamachandraReddy What I am doing is trying to teach myself java and practising via a certain YouTuber who teaches java. What he did is exactly what I am doing so I have no idea what he is parsing. All I know is that the issue is the Date function. I am told it is deprecated yet in the video he is able to use the Date function well.  When I type Date dob; Date is underlined the error says "cannot find symbol even after importing java.util.date. so what now??